# Printing from Windows Service instance - can't see printers

Tags: printing, windows-service

I'm banging my head against a wall with this.

I'm trying to call an external app (Foxit Reader) in order to print a PDF to a network or locally installed printer (I've tried both) from a windows service.

The service is logging on as the domain admin account (at the moment just so I can rule out permissions) and runs a chunk of .NET code using `Process.Start` in order to call Foxit and silently print/close the app.

I had this working a few weeks ago, but all of a sudden it's stopped and I don't understand why.

No matter what I do, the app just silently fails. I don't get any errors in event viewer but the app itself stays open which suggests it's not working.

I tried running as local system and I get a popup on the server telling me the app wants to show a message. The message is an error dialog saying "an attempt was made to reference a token that does not exist".

Is there any reason a user account running in a Windows service context wouldn't be able to see printers?

Comment: Turns out the server just needed a reboot as weird stuff was going on!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Server just needed a reboot...

Relief and frustration combined!